# Trying to find email ticket system

Tags: email

Im looking for an email ticket system, with an API. I have downloaded osticket, but it don't have an API.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

http://mailchimp.com/

This is a really awesome service that has a great API.

Comment: Is that a ticket system like osTicket?